# Firebase filter data by name and city in swift2

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I´m trying to get data from Firebase depending on the name and city from object. 
My firebase tree looks like this:

```
MYAPP
Object:
   - 12837291ß2837(a random ID):
     "name": "test"
     "city": "Hong Kong"
   - 12382133193u2:
     "name": "test"
     "city": "Paris"
   - 2137829128738: 
     "name": "test2"
     "city": "Frankfurt"
```

So for example i just want to get the Object where the name is "test" and the city is "Hong Kong".

i tried sth like this but i dont get any Data:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://myRef")
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Object").queryEqualToValue("test").observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
```

I also added rules in Firebase like :

```
".indexOn": "Object"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with it doesn't work? Are you getting any errors? What are you expecting to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: actually nothing happens. I want to fetch the objects where name = test and city = HongKong for example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems:

1. your query doesn't match your data structure
2. you can only filter on one property.

#### Your query doesn't match your data structure

To sort/filter you first specify the property that you want to filter on and then the filtering operation. Since the value you specify is from the `name` property, the correct query is:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://myRef")
let query = ref.queryOrderedByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("test")
query.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

#### You can only filter on one property

Firebase Database only supports ordering/querying on a single properties. See [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase).